# Custom named crush dump by container variable

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, dump

There is possibility to make a custom script to handle crash dumps (ref. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html) by putting it after pipe.

`sysctl kernel.core_pattern="|/script.sh -p %h.%e"`.

**Now I'd like to append at the end of the name my custom variable, which varies across containers.**
More or less result should be: `|/script.sh -p %h.%e.$containervar` - evaluated during script call.
The problem with this approach is the environment variable gets resolved during assignment, which is call to `sysctl kernel.core_pattern="/script.sh -p %h.%e.$containervar"` - a container, which sets this up, has the var empty.

Entering another namespace `containervar=$(nsenter -t $PID -a echo $containervar)` (`PID` obtained via `%P` in pattern), which I suspect is called by host during `/script.sh`, doesn't help either. I tried couple other things by trial and error, like different brackets, functions, backticks (ASCII 0x60), `eval` and above.

I'm using Azure Kubernetes Services version: 1.20.9, one node - ubuntu 18.04 LTS, runtime: containerd.

Comment: You used `kubernetes` tag, are you using Kubernetes? If yes, which version are you using and which solution did you use to setup a cluster? Which container runtime are you using? Do you have worker nodes or just one node? Please add more details to your question and make your [issue reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MikolajS. Edited the question with required info. There's not much to this other than that. I'm just looking for a way to not resolve the variable during assingment, aside of making a shared file with containers' data or scanning all namespaces from a node perspective (which I'm aware of).